# How can I check whether a string is a (very big) number?

Tags: c#, string, validation, numbers

I need to make a number validation for specified string. The problem is, **the string could be a large number**, larger than any numeric type in C# can represent, so I can't use TryParse functions, because they will give only information about whether they can convert to those types.

It should take into account -/+, separator, and current culture settings.

I found some solutions using regular expressions, but all of them miss some details. And I'm not good at regular expressions

Comment: Why don't you show us what Regexes you've tried, and what you don't like about them. Regex seems like a good fit, but I don't want to suggest things you don't like.

Comment: What is missing from the regular expressions you find? It really does look like you need a good regular expression.

Comment: Unit tests are your friend concerning whether the regular expression works.

Comment: I have to downvote for not using the latest version of C#, which has exactly what you want, and instead you want to roll your own solution. If it's the price of a new Visual Studio you balk at, how much will it cost you to write, test, and maintain your custom solution?

Comment: I suggest laying down your requirements. Give examples of what numbers you need to match. That would aid anyone in constructing a suitable regex pattern and is better than reverse engineering the provided regex that you don't seem too confident about.

Comment: @Jay - Your argument about not using the latest VS seems hardly fair. Few of us have direct control over our budgets or tools sets, and while we strive for strict logic in our code, we can't expect to always find it in the decisions of our management.

Comment: I'm sorry, I found that I can use C# 4.0, I have installed the previous version of framework and didn't noticed that I can use C#4.0 to create application for previous versions of framework

Comment: @Jay Bazuzi - yes, it's completely reasonable that every time Microsoft decides to release a new version of something that every company on the planet should dump everything they've spent 10's of thousands to purchase and spend more 10's of thousands to purchase all new stuff. One might actually think you used to work at Microsoft or something.

Comment: @Joel: Guilty! I admit to having worked on exactly the product I think you should buy! I admit severe bias. One bit of feedback we got from customers a lot was that we should be releasing much more often; difficult to reconcile that with feedback that upgrading is too hard / to expensive / not worth it. That's OK: I get both sides.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use [`BigInteger`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.numerics.biginteger.aspx) if you are using C# 4.0 and the numbers are integers.

It `Represents an arbitrarily large signed integer.`

Use the [`TryParse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268301.aspx) method to avoid the possible exception from [`Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268231.aspx) (unless you are *certain* that the passed in string will always be a valid integer).

Comment: @Nick Martyshchenko - both `Parse` and `TryParse` will use the current culture settings. They also have overloads that specifically allow you to pass in a `IFormatProvider` such as a `CultureInfo`.

Comment: Am I miss something and `BigInteger` can store floating points?

Comment: Isn't this an overkill approach when the OP just wants to validate the format?

Comment: @Nick Martyshchenko - No, as the name suggests, it will only store Integers. The OP hasn't specified floats, however.

Comment: @Nick Martyshchenko - `culture settings` are respected by all the built it `Parse` and `TryParse` methods. I had read the question as meaning integers - you are right, he may have meant floats.

Comment: @Pieter - more overkill than RegEx?

Comment: Hmmmm. Got a point there. *Maybe* if his current app is not in .NET 4 and he would have to install .NET 4 on 1400 client computers, maybe it would be overkill.

Comment: In that case he could use an open source implementation, such as: http://intx.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 3):

If you use .NET 4.0 you can use [BigInteger](http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2009/05/23/net-framework-4-0-introducing-biginteger.aspx). It contains a [TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd268289.aspx) that accepts an `IFormatProver` that will do what you need. `BigInteger` has an unlimited size, so it is not possible that the numbers you need are larger than what `BigInteger` can handle.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at http://www.regexlib.com/Search.aspx?k=numeric&c=-1&m=5&ps=20. http://regexlib.com/ contains many examples of regular expressions, and there must be one that suits your requirements.